# While creating express project using terminal, why every imported libraries comes with "var"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

While I am creating a new express project using terminal (command "express myapp"), all the imported dependencies are comes with var by default.

Sample:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
```

What my understanding is, we should use "const" if we no need to change any references. Then,

> Why above dependencies automatically generated with var?. Should I
>   change all these things into cont from var?. If i do so, does it make
>   any issues?.

Comment: It's mostly down to compatibility. `var` works everywhere. Also, `express` is a pretty old module that predates Node 4. It might be possible that this portion of the code was never updated. Don't fix what ain't broke. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why above dependencies automatically generated with var?

Cause `const` is "quite" new (+4 years), and therefore there might be old nodejs instances that are still running and they have to be supported. Or no one saw a need to change it (cause it works and will work forever).

> Should I change all these things into cont from var?

If you got some freetime that would make sense.

> If i do so, does it make any issues?

No, it rather solves issues, as `var`s can cause some conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it was done before release of `es6` , and may be the project does not include `babel` probably it would had been `import` statement instead of `require` if it was post es6 release.

Also if your project is supporting browsers above ie10 , then you can use replace with `const`

Comment: It's server-side JS. It isn't going to be running on any browser.